# Is there any method to update hyperparameters following the addition of data in a dataset?

Tags: cross-validation, optimization, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, boosting

I have a small dataset that I'm currently using python GridSearchCV to search hyperparameters. From time to time I increase this dataset and have to train again all of my regressors(I'm using sklearn methods - SVM, Adaboost and GradientBoosting and XGboost) and use GridSearchCV to find another best hyperparameters set.
As the data growth and the train time growth, but the set of hyperparameters don't change, and I have to manually change the search space to find optimal hyperparameters. Is there a way to refit data and automatically change the search space to a "better one"?